# Customize AWS Amplify cognito login/register component?

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In the tutorial - https://medium.com/@nickwang_58849/i-got-the-following-error-after-following-the-steps-82757cfaf9f0, it uses `amplify-authenticator` of npm package `@aws-amplify/auth` to login and register.

**auth.component.html** has just one line,

```
<amplify-authenticator></amplify-authenticator>
```

**auth.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.component.css']
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

However, I will need to have a customized login (will need to add some required attributes when registering. And need to style the login/register controls). How to do it?

**Is there any example of user write the login UI and just call the authentication (by amplify?) to log in cognito?**

Comment: Why is 'app-root' placed in a comment? Do you have a selector for 'app-root'?

Comment: Does that code work without a form?  Interesting. Or perhaps the form is in the component template?  Have you looked there?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda, `amplify-authenticator` uses aws amplify js to render the form. I cannot find the string `amplify-authenticator` in other files.

Comment: @ca9163d9 Perhaps you have to address your investigation on how to customize `amplify-authenticator` loging form. I think this has nothing to do with aws or aws-cognito.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda, yes, it should be an amplify problem.

Answer (score 4):

> need to style the login/register controls. How to do it?

If you're using the latest Amplify modules (April 2020) you can customize the look and feel using CSS:

```
:root {
  --amplify-primary-color: #008000;
  --amplify-primary-tint: #0000FF; 
  --amplify-primary-shade: #008000;
}
```

and you can customize the text:

```
<AmplifySignIn headerText="My Custom Sign In Header" slot="sign-in" />
<AmplifySignUp headerText="My Customer Sign Up Header" slot="sign-up" />
```

Docs: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/ui-components#customization

Tutorial from scratch: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-framework-announces-new-rearchitected-ui-component-and-modular-javascript-libraries/

Migrating to the latest UI packages:
https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/ui-components#migration-guide

Comment: Most complete answer at this moment. Unfortunately AWS official docs are very brief regarding customization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should address your investigation on how to customize the `amplify-authenticator` take  look for the docs: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/angular#signup-configuration

Also, this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53527205/2890724